# Move Oracle tables to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g

I have Oracle database on remote server and postgres database on my PC. Whats the best way to transfer the Oracle tables from remote Oracle database to Postgres database on my PC?

Comment: use the internet if it has enough babdwidth. if not find another way.

Comment: postgres can handle most standard file formats, what formats can your oracle client export?

Comment: Dump the schema and convert by hand. Then export tables as CSV from Oracle, then import with the PostgreSQL `COPY` command.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/

Translates create syntax of one database into a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to transfer through Pentaho Kettle spoon job. It was easier and quick. Just establish source and destination database connection by configuring the ODBC driver for Oracle and JDBC driver for Postgres.